# SSL Certificate and SSL Flags not working together

Tags: powershell, iis

I am trying to update a binding but both SSL certificate and SSL flag property are not working together. If I set `sslFlags=1` it is not attaching SSL certificate to Binding but if I leave `sslFlags` property it adds SSL certificate but then I miss `sslFlags` property.

```psh
New-ItemProperty $(Join-Path iis:\Sites $sitename) -Name bindings -Value @{
  protocol="https";
  bindingInformation="10.35.5.7:$($port):$($hostheader)";
  certificateStoreName="My";
  certificateHash=$thumbprint;
  sslFlags=1
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Correct way of creating SNI based binding is:

**to create binding:**

New-Item -Path "IIS:\SslBindings\$ipAddress!$port!$hostheader" -SSLFlags 1  -Value $cert | out-null  # Update Certificate information

**to update certificate information:**

New-ItemProperty $(join-path iis:\Sites $sitename) -name bindings -value @{protocol="https";bindingInformation="$($ipAddress):$($port):$($hostheader)";certificateStoreName="My";certificateHash=$thumbprint;sslFlags=1}